# Keep White Spaces when saving UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving text from a `UITextView` to `NSUserDefaults` but when it saves all the white space is trimmed. I'd like to keep it as is.

For example, I want the output to look as typed, such as:

```
I am a brown fox.

I can run fast.

Blah blah blah.
```

Here's my code for saving:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.myTextView.text forKey:@"myTextView"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Here's my code for output:

```
NSString *outputString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"myTextView"];
```

Here's how the output looks:

```
I am a brown fox. I can run fast. Blah blah blah.
```

It goes from 3 paragraphs to one.

I would like to have this text displayed in an email.

**SOLUTION**:

I need to replace the occurrence of `\n` with `<br>`

```
NSString *correctString = [outputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"];
```

Comment: Which white space is lost? Show your code for losing and using the saved text. There is no reason why any white space would disappear.

Comment: The space between each paragraph. All text is pushed together into one paragraph.

Comment: Again, update your question with your code for setting the text of the text view with the saved text. Also show the incorrect result for comparison to what you want.

Comment: Make sure to add the information that you are trying to use the string to compose an email next time. That missing information was very key to helping you solve the problem.

Comment: have you achieved what you wanted?

Comment: Syed: Yes, I added the solution above when I solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
NSData *stringData = [myTextView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stringData forKey:@"myTextViewText"];
```

and do following to get it

```
NSData *stringData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTextViewText"];
 NSString *myString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: In this case the string is logged out showing the paragraph form, but the string that displays in my mail compose sheet is still one line

Comment: when you eMail then it is in one line or before that?

Comment: When I log out the string before I present the compose sheet it shows as it was typed, but inside the mail sheet it's all compressed to one line.